# save() form from django don't save in DB

Tags: python, django

I want to save a username in database, but it doesn't work. Below is the code. I've created a DB named User and I'm trying to save the user who has been taking by the input from the html I've created. And my database User contains only username field. I used the UserCrationForm as default, and my database appear as polls_user in phpmyadmin. I don't think that's the problem. When I'm trying to save from shell, its working, using the save modelform.

```
views.py

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            q = form.save(commit=False)
            q.username = request.username
            q.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/login')
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Error")
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = UserCreationForm()
    return render_to_response('polls/register.html', args, context_instance= RequestContext(request))


register.html

{% block content %}
   <h2> Register</h2>
        <form action="/polls/login/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I cant see where the problem is.
Someone help?

Comment: Doesn't work? Do you get any error messages anywhere? If you get nothing try adding some logging messages to help you debug.

Comment: And add the form and it's save method.

Comment: no error messages.
i dont know if its have a connection, but i use another 2 models, that have foreignkey with this one, any problem with that?

Comment: Try to print `form.errors` to see if there're some invalid fields when you post the form

Comment: You should past your form.py code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here: `q.username = request.username` .It should be:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            q = User() #import your own User model here. 
            q.username = request.user.username
            q.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/login')
```

PS: This will only get you the username of the logged in user.

**EDIT:**
(*from comments*)
As you can see, `UserCreationForm` is a modelform, where in meta class, model is auth.User model(check [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L86)). So your data is being saved in auth.User. So override the `UserCreationForm` like this (If you want to use the `UserCreationForm`):

```
#form

class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
         model = PollUser #Your poll user model
         fields = ("username",)

#view

if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MyUserCreationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
               ....
```

For this solution, you have to keep in mind that, you need to subclass `PollUser` model from `auth.User` model. If you want to use your own `PollUser` model (not subclassing from `auth.User` model), then I will suggest you to make a new modelform for `PollUser` and not use `UserCreationForm`.

Comment: You are still not getting any username or just blank space? I think you should get an error if you are using django's default authentication model (auth.User model) because username can't be duplicate entry in here. Also, can you show your model definition here if you are not using django's default auth model?

Comment: class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

Comment: ive done it now, but its save the data in auth_user and not in polls_user, which is my DB...
How to correct this?

Comment: @CapCapi , actually you are using UserCreationForm, which is a modelform. In this form's meta class, the model is auth.User. So its saving data in auth.User model. I have added an edit section for clarification.